# Compare first three characters of two strings

Tags: java

Strings s1 and s2 will always be of length 1 or higher.

How can I speed this up?

```
int l1 = s1.length();

if (l1 > 3) { l1 = 3; }

if (s2.startsWith(s1.substring(0,l1))) 
{
 // do something..
}
```

Regex maybe?

Comment: Using very short variable names does *not* speed your program up! ;)

Comment: Citing from below: "I have to go through all the words of a 20 mb txt file". You have a too narrow view on your problem if you only consider two strings at a time. Consider the whole problem and use a better algorithm, using tries is a good suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a trie implemented as an array for the first 3 chars and as a sorted array for the rest of them. IO is of course the biggest factor of speeding the program up but small changes like these can improve the program with a few seconds.

Answer (score 9):

#### Rewrite to avoid object creation

Your instincts were correct. The creation of new objects (substring()) is not very fast and it means that each one created must incur g/c overhead as well.

This might be a lot faster:

```
static boolean fastCmp(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1.regionMatches(0, s2, 0, 3);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this as a `Comparator`, i.e. returning an `int` instead of a `boolean`?

Answer (score 6):

This seems pretty reasonable. Is this really too slow for you? You sure it's not premature optimization?

Comment: I have to go through all the words of a 20 mb txt file so it needs to be fast. :P

Comment: I think you should isolate this in a method and, if it later appears too slow, you can optimize it. Meanwhile, make sure this is really the slow part of your program(perhaps you should be more concerned about IO speed, for example?)

Comment: nalo, in this case, I would perhaps look at tries (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).  You could then limit the depth to 3.

Comment: It creates a new object with the substring method, so, no, it's not the best approach. Using regionMatches() is most likely a lot faster.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (s2.startsWith(s1.substring(0, Math.min(3, s1.length())) {..};
```

Btw, there is nothing slow in it. `startsWith` has complexity `O(n)`

Another option is to compare the char values, which might be more efficient:

```
boolean match = true;
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(Math.min(s1.length(), 3), s2.length()); i++) {
    if (s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i)) {
       match = false;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: if s1 is of one character length, and s2 starts with that one character, this will evaluate to true, whereas it would not in the original example.

Comment: it will in the original example as well

Comment: StartsWith() isn't the problem...The problem is  the substring() which allocates a new string.

Comment: might as well break; as soon as the match is false (it could save a couple of compares ;)

Comment: hm, which appears to be what you've answered as well, but translated in Java.

Comment: `O(n)` is still slower than `O(log n)` or `O(1)`, especially if the constant factor for `O(1)` is zero.

Answer (score 2):

My java isn't that good, so I'll give you an answer in C#:

```
int len = Math.Min(s1.Length, Math.Min(s2.Length, 3));
for(int i=0; i< len; ++i)
{
    if (s1[i] != s2[i])
       return false;
}
return true;
```

Note that unlike yours and Bozho's, this does not create a new string, which would be the slowest part of your algorithm.

Comment: Regarding "creating a new string": While `String#substring()` will necessarily create a new `String` object, in the common library implementation, it does not need to copy characters; the returned `String` merely refers to the same character array underlying the original string, with different bounding indexes. `String#substring()`'s documentation does not guarantee that arrangement, and this paper discusses an optimization to take advantage of that flexibility: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1411747

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do this

```
if (s1.length() > 3 && s2.length() > 3 && s1.indexOf (s2.substring (0, 3)) == 0)
{
  // do something..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is context missing here:
What are you trying to scan for? What type of application? How often is it expected to run?

These things are important because different scenarios call for different solutions:

1. If this is a one-time scan then this is probably unneeded optimization. Even for a 20MB text file, it wouldn't take more than a couple of minutes in the worst case.
2. If you have a set of inputs and for each of them you're scanning all the words in a 20MB file, it might be better to sort/index the 20MB file to make it easy to look up matches and skip the 99% of unnecessary comparisons. Also, if inputs tend to repeat themselves it might make sense to employ caching.

Other solutions might also be relevant, depending on the actual problem.

But if you boil it down only to comparing the first 3 characters of two strings, I believe the code snippets given here are as good as you're going to get - they're all O(1)*, so there's no drastic optimization you can do.

*The only place where this might not hold true is if getting the length of the string is O(n) rather than O(1) (which is the case for the strlen function in C++), which is not the case for Java and C# string objects.